# Objects under Objects

Tags: javascript

I am selecting value from Drop down and want to use it in following way.
Like here I am returning value from drop down in variable selectedtext.

```js
  <p style="font-size:150%;margin-left:20%; margin-top:50px"> Sources :
        <select id="drop" name="drop">
            <option value="0">Select Source</option>
            <option value="1">RBSK</option>
            <option value="2">MIDRS</option>
            <option value="3">ATM </option>
            <option value="4">RT </option>
        </select>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $("#drop").change(function () {
       var  selectedText = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
//var selectedValue = $(this).val();
//alert("Selected Text: " + selectedText + " Value: " + selectedValue);
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Now I want to use this value here:

```js
var deMapping = {
            RBSK: {'dsUID': 'tdTwLUxcQ8R', rootNodeName: 'RBSK_GIS_Indicator', orgUnitTagName: 'MCTSCode', des: [
                {
                    xmlid: "Childhood_Diseases_0_6_Female",
                    dataElement: "oV163sbcJ0N",
                    categoryOptionCombo: "Cmzbo9LD8pJ"
                }
                ]},
           ATM:{},
           ABC:{},
           DEF:{}
};
```

I want to use selectedText in this way:

deMapping.RBSK.des[5].categoryOptionCombo; //Here it will return the correct value of 6th element in des array.

Now I want to replace the RBSK with selectedText which user selects from dropdown.

So if User selects ATM it should return values related with ATM. Like   deMapping.selectedText.des[5].categoryOptionCombo; becomes  deMapping.ATM.des[5].categoryOptionCombo;    if user selects ATM from dropdown

Can anybody help?

Comment: can you please clarify what do you mean? do you want to get the object with id of "RBSK" in your example or do you want to check something? it's not fully understood

Comment: I want to compare the value stored in variable with deMapping object:  Like var a="RBSK"  then how I can compare only this string from deMapping.

Comment: I'm sorry, your explanation still isn't clear, your variable a has a value of "RBSK" you can get the value of RBSK from the deMapping object by using `deMapping[a]` is this what you wanted?

Comment: I have edit the whole question again  Now please help if you can.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you get the value from deMapping (in this case I alert it but you can do anything you want with it of course):

```
$(function () {
  $("#drop").change(function () {
    var selectedText = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
    alert(deMapping[selectedText].des.categoryOptionCombo);
  });
});
```